# Search a vector of strings for all instances of a string in another a vector of strings

Tags: r, string

I have a some data in a tibble with a number column and an associated sentience. I  also have a vector of about ~450 shorter strings that I want to check each sentience for. Ultimately I want to know the sum value of the number entries associated with each of the ~450 strings (after prorating each of the sentences based on the number of hits - e.g., if one of the sentences is associated with a number value of 3 and had two hits from the 450 strings I'd want to add 1.5 to each of their tallies, see examples 1 and 2 both of which appear in the first "sentience" string)

The example below gets to the "final_result" that I want for the 4 example strings, but is not practical for the ~450 strings. (I'm not particularly wedded to building a large table of 2 + ~450 columns to do this, so if this can be done with a single list return for the search matches, or any other way, that's fine.)

Can someone suggest a more scalable and appropriate way to arrive at the same basic output?

Thanks very much.

````
##Tibble with some strings and associated numbers
pacman::p_load(stringi, tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
entries <- tibble("numbers" = rnorm(100),
                    "strings" = stri_rand_strings(100, 15, "[A-Za-z]"))

#Strings known to show up for example
strings_to_find <- c("NJad", "GNl", "Qaw", "bQ")

#Answers in the form of a table
answers_as_table <- entries %>% 
  mutate(String1 = str_detect(entries$strings, pattern = strings_to_find[[1]]),
         String2 = str_detect(entries$strings, pattern = strings_to_find[[2]]),
         String3 = str_detect(entries$strings, pattern = strings_to_find[[3]]),
         String4 = str_detect(entries$strings, pattern = strings_to_find[[4]]))

#Find the number of strings in each entry
answers_as_table$CountofHits <- rowSums(answers_as_table[,3:6])
#prorate accordingly
answers_as_table$proration <- answers_as_table$numbers / answers_as_table$CountofHits

#Find the sum of the prorated amount
SumString1 <- sum(answers_as_table[answers_as_table$String1,8])
SumString2 <- sum(answers_as_table[answers_as_table$String2,8])
SumString3 <- sum(answers_as_table[answers_as_table$String3,8])
SumString4 <- sum(answers_as_table[answers_as_table$String4,8])


(final_product <- tibble("strings_to_find" = strings_to_find, 
       "Sums" = c(SumString1, SumString2, SumString3, SumString4)))```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A base R attempt for giggles:

```
g <- stack(sapply(strings_to_find, grep, x=entries$strings, simplify=FALSE))
g$numbers <- entries$numbers[g$values]
g$prorata <- ave(g$numbers, g$values, FUN=function(x) x/length(x))
out <- aggregate(prorata ~ ind, data=g, sum)
out

#   ind    prorata
#1 NJad -0.3132269
#2  GNl -0.3132269
#3  Qaw  0.1836433
#4   bQ  0.3575099
```

Compares well:

```
out == final_product
#      ind prorata
#[1,] TRUE    TRUE
#[2,] TRUE    TRUE
#[3,] TRUE    TRUE
#[4,] TRUE    TRUE
```

Comment: You might have to look for word boundaries `\\b` before and after your search term, e.g. `grepl("\\bTRAIL\\b", c("TRAIL","TRAIL RUN","TRAILRUN"))` - I don't know if it's possible to match `TRAIL` but not `TRAIL RUN` however, if these are going to be long strings compared. You might just have to do `"TRAIL" == c("TRAIL","TRAIL RUN","TRAILRUN")`

Comment: Thanks! It turns out that I need to exclude results where the search pattern is a substring of what appears in the search vector. (E.g., I'm looking for entries in all caps. Perhaps one is "TRAIL", and another is "TRAIL RUN" and still another is "TRAILRUN". In that case I only want a positive return on "TRAIL" not the others.)
Appending a lookahead like (?![A-Z]{2,}|[:space:][A-Z]) to each of string in strings_to_find works, but grep doesn't work with lookarounds.
Is there a better way to modify the strings? Or can one incorporate str_count in lieu of grep/how?

Comment: Sorry - I 
adding the a lookahead to my regex (seems to) solve my problem. Is there a way to do what you did using the stringr version of grep?
edit: paste(strings_to_find, "(?![A-Z]{2,}|[:space:][A-Z]{2,})", sep = "")

Comment: @user8150796 - I don't think `grep` with or without `perl=TRUE` supports the regex that you are using, as it complains about being invalid.

Comment: Yeah; that seems to be the case. It does work, however, with str_xxx in the stringr package (tidyverse). Is there a way to rewrite this line:
g <- stack(sapply(strings_to_find, grep, x=entries$strings, simplify=FALSE))
to use str_count?

Comment: Actually - I may have sorted it out; I htink I need str_which and to change "x=entries$strings" to "pattern=entries$strings". Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

We can loop over the `vector` and create the columns

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
answers_as_table <- map2_dfc(strings_to_find,
        str_c("String", seq_along(strings_to_find)),
         ~ entries %>% 
              transmute(!! .y := str_detect(strings, .x))) %>%
        mutate(CountofHits = rowSums(.)) 
 sumstring <- answers_as_table %>%
                summarise(across(starts_with('String'), sum))
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you.
One more consideration I forgot - a string may appear more than once in a sentience. I think this works fine if I use str_count instead of str_detect?
Thanks again!

Comment: @user8150796 If your intention is to just detect the string, `str_detect` is useful.  If it is to count the number of occurence of the same string, you can change it to `str_count`